# Scrolling outside window FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, textarea, fancybox-2

There is a editor textarea in FancyBox window. When I put a lot text at editor the window Fancy centered  and is not scrolling. The part of text is outside. How make scrolling all block fancybox? (not scrolling content inside box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to mix some fancybox API options, specifically `fitToView`, `autoCenter` and the `overlay locked` like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        maxWidth: "90%", // keeps fancybox width in viewport - adjust to your preference
        fitToView: false, // allows extend fancybox outside viewport 
        autoCenter: false, // allows scroll fancybox along the body
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false // allows scrolling outside fancybox
            }
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hvxtk8m5/)**

Comment: Can you tell me, how show header block in fancy box?